# How to efficiently manipulate the contents of nested lists in R

Tags: r, nested-lists, list-manipulation

I am currently working with nested lists containing data on auto parts, here's an example of what that looks like:

```
Partslist                   <- setNames(list(setNames(vector(mode="list", 5),  paste("L", 3, "_",c("type", "year", "parts available", "last update", "make"), sep=""))), "Partslist")
Partslist$Partslist$L3_make <- setNames(vector(mode="list", 2),  c("BMW", "Toyota"))

Partslist$Partslist$L3_make$BMW$Engine    <-setNames(vector(mode="list", 6),  c("L1_type", "L1_year", "L1_parts available", "L1_last update", "L1_components", "L1_status"))
Partslist$Partslist$L3_make$BMW$Powertrain<-setNames(vector(mode="list", 6),  c("L1_type", "L1_year", "L1_parts available", "L1_last update", "L1_components", "L1_status"))
Partslist$Partslist$L3_make$Toyota$Engine <-setNames(vector(mode="list", 6),  c("L1_type", "L1_year", "L1_parts available", "L1_last update", "L1_components", "L1_status"))
Partslist$Partslist$L3_make$Toyota$other  <-setNames(vector(mode="list", 6),  c("L1_type", "L1_year", "L1_parts available", "L1_last update", "L1_components", "L1_status"))
```

The main challenge is that these lists are irregular, meaning I do not know a priori how deep the nesting is going to be on individual branches.

What I need is a scalable approach to select and manipulate the data on every level of the nested list, i.e. update prices, quantities, etc.

In short, I find myself unable to come up with an approach that's able to deal with the constantly changing depth of the list.

One possible and easy to implement - yet ugly - way around this, was to form string-expressions of the required manipulations and then use eval(parse(text="")).

That would look something like this:

```
target.string <- "Autoparts$L3_make$BMW$L2_components$Engine§L1_type" 
parts.data<-"hybrid 3i"

eval(parse(text=paste("target.string", "<-", parts.data, sep="")))
```

However, I don't want to resort to that, there must be a better way... I am grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason for using this data structure? My default data structure would be a (long-format) data.table.

Comment: Well, certainly a good point, I might want to consider long format. But, for the time being, let's say I am stuck with those lists. Not sure whether that's actually compelling, but I am, so is there anything obvious that I am missing?

Comment: Have you looked at the `purrr` package? Please don’t use images of data without the data object, as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. [For multiple reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Reproducible questions make it easy for other who may want to help, copy data easily so potential solutions can be tested and verified.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all the kinds of things you want to do, but an efficient way to work with deeply nested lists is to use vectors as indices into the top level.

```
# Your desired index into autoparts was
# autoparts$L3_make$BMW$L2_components$Engine§L1_type

index <- c("L3_make", "BMW", "L2_components", "Engine", "L1_type")

Autoparts[[index]] <- parts.data
```

An earlier version of this answer said that indexing by name wasn't allowed.  That was wrong.  What's not allowed is mixing indexing by name with indexing by number.  The numbers will get converted to character and be interpreted as names.

Comment: Thanks, it is a viable solution, at least capable of getting rid of eval. Your final remark however addresses what I (implicitly) sought to verify. Since indexing by name won't work, I will have to think of something else...

Comment: Whoops, my comment was wrong.  You can index by name.  I'll fix the answer.

Comment: Thanks for coming back. Whilst I was thinking about the index solution I came to wonder, doesn't it imply a priori knowledge of the (entire) list structure?

Comment: Numeric indexing does, but if you can index by name, I think you only need local knowledge -- the same as your `eval(parse(` solution.